# Edit Symfony entity from the frontend

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony app using multiple entities.

A third-party analytic tool plugs to my database to create reportings.

What I would like to achieve, is being able to update the Symfony entity from the frontend in order to add new fields to the database tables (in order to get the new fields showing up in the reporting tool).

Anyone has a idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with "frontend" do you mean your Symfony app?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the documentation, especially the `forms` part: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you wan't to be able to add fields to your entity dynamicaly.
I don't know if this is doable and if so, it would probably be messy and unsecure.

What you can do however is using sub-entities with dynamic key => values fields.

You should have one main entity, an entity with the list of your dynamic fields, a many to many relation between your main entity and your fields entities and a third entity with the actual values from those fields.